# Insertion in Circularly Linked List at the beginning

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

I am inserting at the circularly linked list at the beginning but output is printing some garbage value.

```
typedef struct Node
   {
    int info;
    struct Node *next;
   }node;
 node *head;
 void insert(int x)   //x will the value given by the user
   {
             node *ptr,*ptr1;
             //ptr1 for pointing the last node again to first node

             ptr=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
             ptr->info=x;
             if(head==NULL)
               {
                  ptr->next=head;
                  head=ptr;
                  ptr1=ptr;
               }
               else
               {
                   ptr->next=head;
                   head=ptr;

               }
            head->next=ptr1;
    }

  void show()
  {
       node *temp=head;
       while(temp!=NULL)
       {
       printf("%d",temp->info);
       temp=temp->next;
       }
       printf("\n");
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems, one leading to an infinite list and the other to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The infinite list you get when you insert the first node in the list because of this:

```
head->next=ptr1;
```

By that point `head` and `ptr` *and* `ptr1` all point to the same node, so with the above assignment you say that the next node in the list is... itself!.

---

The undefined behavior is in the other case, when the list isn't empty, and the cause of that is *the same assignment* as above:

```
head->next=ptr1;
```

Here the variable `ptr1` haven't been initialized, and uninitialized local (non-static) variables have an *indeterminate* value and using those variable except to initialize them leads to undefined behavior.

Actually, the undefined behavior doesn't happen at the moment of the assignment, but it will happen when you next try to dereference `head->next`, as that pointer is invalid.

---

The simple solution to both these problems? Don't do that last assignment!

Comment: But then how I'll implement the circularly list.

Comment: @Beginner By making the *last* nodes `next` pointer point to `head`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign anything to ptr1 in your else{} branch, yet later you store ptr1 value as head->next. Since ptr1 is uninitialized, you get garbage when you print your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
package linkedlists;
class CircularlyLinkedList<T> {

/**
 * static node class which keep generic as a value
 */
public static class Node<T>{
    private T value;
    private Node next;

    /**
     * Node constructor
     * @param value store node T data
     * @param next reference of next node
     */
    public Node(T value, Node next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    /**
     * node's value getter
     * @return node's value
     */
    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    /**
     * next node of current node
     * @return next's node
     */
    public Node getNext(){
        return this.next;
    }

    /**
     * setter of next property
     * @param next new next node
     */
    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
       this.value = value;
    }
}

private Node tail = null;
private int size = 0;

/**
 * circularly linked list constructor
 */
public CircularlyLinkedList() {}

/**
 * size property getter
 * @return circularly linked list size
 */
public int getSize() {
    return this.size;
}

/**
 * is list contain element
 * @return true if circularly linked list contain 0 element, else return false
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.size == 0;
}

/**
    if(this.size > 1)
 * perform rotate operation if there are more than 1 element
            */
    public void rotate() {
        this.tail = this.tail.next;
}

/**
 * add new node to head of circularly linked list
 * @param value new node integer value
 */
public void addFirst(T value) {
    if(this.size == 0) {
        tail = new Node(value, null);
        tail.setNext(tail);
    }else{
        Node newValue = new Node(value, this.tail.getNext());
        tail.setNext(newValue);
    }
    size++;
}

/**
 * add new node to head of circularly linked list
 * @param value new node T value
 */
public void addLast(T value) {
    this.addFirst(value);   // by calling ad first we added node to the head
    tail = tail.getNext();  // then we change added node as tail, now it became last node
}

/**
 * getter method of tail node
 * @return circularly linked list's tail
 */
public Node<T> getTail() {
    return this.tail;
}

/**
 * Overrided toString method of CircularlyLinkedList
 * @return string that shows CircularlyLinkedList's values
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = "[ ";

    // head node
    Node temp = this.tail.getNext();
    do{ //loop until head{
        str += (temp.getValue() + " " );
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }while(temp != this.getTail().next); // loop until arrive head again


    return str + "]";
}

/**
 * compare CircularlyLinkedLists node by node
 * @param obj CircularlyLinkedList that will be compared "this"
 * @return whether given CircularlyLinkedList have same content with
 * "this" or not
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){

    if(obj == null) return false;

    if(obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
        return false;

    CircularlyLinkedList cirList = (CircularlyLinkedList)obj;

    // if sizes are not same return false
    if(cirList.getSize() != this.size )
        return false;

    Node walkA = cirList.tail.next; //head node of cirList
    Node walkB = this.tail.next;    // head node of this

    do{
        if(walkA.getValue() != walkB.getValue())
            return false;   // nodes are different

        walkA = walkA.getNext(); //assign next nodes to walkA and walkB
        walkB = walkB.getNext();
    }while(walkA != cirList.getTail().getNext()); // loop until encourage cirList head

    return true; //all elements are same

}
}
```